# In a lognormal distribution, is the median further left than when the variable is logged?

Tags: stata, median, lognormal-distribution, density-estimation

I created a kernel density estimate of the earnings distribution in South Africa in 2017, quarter 4, using Stata.

I summarized the earnings variable, putting a sampling weight as an analytical weight (because the `summarize` command doesn't take sampling weights). I then saved the mean and median, and generated the log mean and log median from those.

I then logged the real earnings variable, and ran a kernel density command on it, with sampling weights. In the graph, I added the abovementioned log mean and log median as vertical lines.

My concern is that the median looks too far to the left. I would have thought that half the area under the curve should be to the left and half to the right. Am I correct in thinking that this looks wrong?

My code is [here](https://pastebin.com/Qd35BsZG). I'm not sure what I did wrong.

[image: Distribution]

Comment: The log of the mean of a lognormal doesn't have any clear reference. Perhaps more to the point, your data are roughly symmetric on logarithmic scale, but not especially close to lognormal. A quantile plot is a better check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the inverse hyperbolic sine transformation (IHS) to log the variable. This tends to $\ln(2) + \ln(x)$ as $x$ gets large, so the values were $\ln(2)$ too big. The IHS should only be used in regressions (as then the level would not matter for the coefficients on regressors).

Comment: You are clearly allowed to answer your question, but here the answer underlines that the original question was misleading!

Comment: I did include my code though? The problem was the `asinh` command, which was in the Pastebin link.

Comment: But yes, I agree that saying I "logged" the variable was misleading.

Comment: If the limit you cite were the only point there would be no gain to using asinh. Let's spell out that the deal is being to accommodate zeros and negative values: how many did you have.

Comment: Only about 50 zero values (out of about 11 000), and no negative. Sorry. I was taught about `asinh` in Honours, but obviously not thoroughly enough, as I finished the course not knowing why it is not always used.

Comment: It is impressive that you were taught it at all and recall that too.

Answer (score 2):

The log of the mean of y will generally not equal the mean of log(y) because of [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality): it will be larger. There's [a similar result](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167715204003104) for medians.

But you have the opposite problem, so that can't be it. Looking at the code, your kernel density has an if condition that constrains the sample, but the `summarize` where you calculate the mean does not. That would be my first guess where to look, but I can't confirm without your data.

My second guess would be the type weights are different in the two calculations. Try using the same type of weight throughout.

Comment: Isn't that the other way round, because the log function is concave?

Comment: @ahorn Yes, thanks for the correction.

Comment: If you agree with me, then it seems Jensen's Inequality doesn't help to explain what went wrong with my graph.

Comment: Seems like I need a MWE with sysuse data.